# Error on authentication while trying to hit Salesforce API for test org

Tags: python, salesforce

I am using the following code to login to our Salesforce orgs, the code works perfectly as long as it is connecting to prod org, but once I change the `endpoint` from `"https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/35.0"` to `"https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/35.0"` to connect to our test org, it failed and showed my `exceptionCode='INVALID_LOGIN'`.

```
from runcmd.java_helper import jvm
from runcmd.logging_helper import get_logger

LOGGER = get_logger(__name__)
ENDPOINT = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/35.0"

def authenticate(username, password, security_token) -> dict:
    """
    Authenticates against salesforce.
    """
    return {
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
        "security_token": security_token
    }
def _build_sf_connection(spark, sf_obj):
    config = jvm(spark).com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig()
    config.setUsername(sf_obj["username"])
    config.setPassword(sf_obj["password"] + sf_obj["security_token"])
    config.setAuthEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
    config.setServiceEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
    LOGGER.info("Username=%s" % sf_obj["username"]) 
    return jvm(spark).com.sforce.soap.partner.Connector.newConnection(config)
```

I checked the login info and they are all correct but I noticed  even though I have changed the endpoint in the code to test.salesforce, it still  trying to connect through login.salesforce .

```
20/05/01 06:13:58 INFO SFConfig: loginURL : https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/35.0
20/05/01 06:14:02 ERROR SFConfig: Exception while creating connection
[LoginFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_LOGIN'
 exceptionMessage='Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.'
 extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have something else that sets login.salesforce.com, maybe java application has it hardcoded in JAR or defined in their own config files... any special reason why it's done through java? have you experimented with https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/ or https://pypi.org/project/pyforce/ and deemed them unfit?

Looking closer at `com.sforce.soap.partner`... hm, looks like "[Partner WSDL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&mode=1&id=000325670)" that's been consumed, had Java classes generated out of it (go to Setup -> API). You could inspect these classes and see if there's anything built in that lets you override at runtime the code generated based on that snippet at bottom of the WSDL.

```
<service name="SforceService">
    <documentation>Sforce SOAP API</documentation>
    <port binding="tns:SoapBinding" name="Soap">
        <soap:address location="https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/48.0"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

If it was just generated and left to its own devices and nobody wants to touch Java... Hm, check if you can have 2 compiled JAR files sitting next to each other and you load test or prod version to Python as needed?

But it really seems like roundabout way of doing things and API v 35 was released ~3 years ago, definitely worth checking your options now.